# Local Firebase Cloud Functions issue with Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-cli

When I start the functions locally (**firebase serve --only functions**), it can read & write the Firestore data but when it comes to send the push notification it fails with the following error. It was working since yesterday. Today i updated my MacOS to Big Sur and then it stopped working.

> Unauthorized Error 401 An error occurred when trying to authenticate
> to the FCM servers.  Make sure the credential used to authenticate
> this SDK has the proper permissions.  See
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for setup instructions.

**Following is the function that tries to send the notification**:

```
exports.test = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, response) => {
    var data = {};
    const token = await util.getTokenByEmail('demouser@gmail.com');
    let payload = {}, notiData = {}, notification = {}
    notification.title = notiData.title = `Test msg`;
    notification.body = `Test msg`;
    notiData.message = `Test msg`;
    payload.notification = notification;
    payload.data = notiData;
   try {
     await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload);
   } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Error: ${e}`); // Unauthorized Error 401
       data.error = e;
   }
   response.status(200).json({ data: data });
});
```

I followed the steps given [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUEQa.png) and also set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="Volumes/demo/Firebase/key.json"
```

I am downloading the key.json from the Firebase -> Settings -> Service Accounts.

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that, I was setting the **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** only for that terminal session. Once I set the path to $HOME/.zshrc, it started working. Thanks for your time and help.